# ZeroMQ cleaning up PULL socket - half-close

Tags: python, zeromq

My problem is kind of trying to half-close a zmq socket.

In simple terms I have a pair of PUSH/PULL sockets in Python.
The PUSH socket never stops sending, but the PULL socket should be able to clean itself up in a following way:

1. Stop accepting any additional messages to the queue
2. Process the messages still in the queue
3. Close the socket etc.

I don't want to affect the PUSH socket in any way, it can keep accumulating its own queue until another PULL socket comes around or that might be there already. The LINGER option doesn't seem to work with recv() (just with send()).

One option might be to have a broker in between with the broker PUSH and receiver PULL HWM set to zero. Then the broker's PULL would accumulate the messages. However, I'd rather not do this. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confusing which socket type will queue messages. According to the [zmq_socket](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-socket) docs, a PUSH socket will queue its messages but a PULL socket doesn't have any type of queuing mechanism.

So what you're asking to be able to do would be something of the following:

1) Stop *recv'ing* any additional messages to the *PULL socket*.
2) Close the socket etc.

The PUSH socket will continue to 'queue' its messages automatically until either the HWM is met (at which it will then block and not queue any more messages) or a PULL socket comes along and starts recv'ing messages.

The case I think you're really concerned about is a slow PULL reader. In which you would like to get all of the currently queued messages in the PUSH socket (at once?) and then quit. This isn't how zmq works, you get one message at a time.

To implement something of this sort, you'll have to wrap the PULL capability with your own queue. You 'continually' PULL the messages into your personal queue (in a different thread?) until you want to stop, then process those messages and quit.